# How to calculate the variance of $(X_1-X_2)^2$?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, variance, mse

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are both a random sample from $\mathrm{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$.

How to calculate variance of $(X_1-X_2)^2$?

Comment: Do both $X_1$ and $X_2$ come from the same distribution or do they differ in terms of the mean and variance?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Both of them follow normal distribution with mean u and variance sigma square. iid

Comment: Have you heard of [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)?

Comment: Well, what is the distribution of  $X_1-X_2$?  Then what is the distribution of  $(X_1-X_2)^2$?  Then what is the variance of  $(X_1-X_2)^2$?

Comment: If both follow the same normal distribution, the answer is $8\sigma^{4}$.

Comment: @TPArrow Exactly how do you conclude there are two degrees of freedom and why do you introduce $\mu$ when the mean of $X_1-X_2$ obviously is zero?

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes, but it would be complex if calculate in that way

Comment: @TPArrow I know that sum of (x1-u)^2 and  (x1-u)^2 follow chi(2) distribution proved by MGF. But I can't figure out the last item since I have to prove independent between this item with the other two items. How you figure out the distribution form?

Comment: @Nicole, just follow the outline in my comment above.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks, I am curious how did you get this answer. TPArrow's answer give some hint, the variance of his distribution is your answer. But how to get that distribution? I try to use MGF but didn't work it out. Thanks

Comment: I just followed @MarkL.Stone's outline. Try to follow it too and tell us at what point you are stuck.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone  I get what you mean, thanks. x1-x2 follows N(0,2sigma^2) using law of MGF and then [(x1-x2)/(2*sigma^2)]^2 follows chi square distribution. Then I get the answer. Right?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the outline provided by @MarkLStone.

First, the distribution of $Z=(X_1-X_2)$ is $\mathrm{N}(0,2\sigma^{2})$.

Next, we know that a squared normal distribution with mean zero and unit variance follows a [Chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with one degree of freedom. Consequently:

$$
\frac{Z^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\sim \chi^{2}(\nu=1)
$$

Hence

$$
Z^{2}\sim 2\sigma^{2}\chi^{2}(\nu=1)
$$

**Edit:** Thanks to @Glen, there is even a faster way than that outlined below:

The variance of the Chi-squared distribution is $2\nu$. Furthermore, a basic property of the variance is $\mathrm{Var}(kX)=k^{2}\mathrm{Var}(X)$. So with $k=2\sigma^{2}$ we arrive immediately at

$$
\mathrm{Var}(Z^{2})=\mathrm{Var}(2\sigma^{2}\chi^{2}_1))=4\sigma^{4}\mathrm{Var}(\chi^{2}_1))=4\sigma^{4}\cdot2=8\sigma^{4}
$$

---

**Old version**

The next step is to know the following relationship between a Chi-squared distribution and the [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution):

$$
\mathrm{If}\: X\sim\chi^{2}(\nu)\;\mathrm{and}\;c>0, \;\mathrm{then}\; cX\sim\mathrm{Gamma}\left(k=\nu/2, \theta=2c\right)
$$

So we have at last:

$$
Z^{2}\sim \mathrm{Gamma}\left(k=1/2, \theta=2\left(2\sigma^{2}\right)\right)
$$

The variance of a gamma distribution is $k\theta^{2}$. So we end up with

$$
\mathrm{Var}(Z^{2})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(4\sigma^{2}\right)^{2}=8\sigma^{4}
$$

Comment: +1 but you can proceed more directly. From your line "$Z^2\sim 2\sigma^2\chi^2(1)$" you can use basic properties of variance ($\text{Var}(kX)=k^2\text{Var}(X)$) and the fact that $\text{Var}$ of a $\chi^2_\nu$ is $2\nu$, immediately obtaining $(2\sigma^2)^2\times 2=8\sigma^4$.

Comment: @Glen_b Right, that's much faster. I added your solution. Many thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yes, I had in mind this solution with the Glen_b variant.  I also had in mind that there would be something left for the OP to do on her homework problem.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks, the need to leave something for the OP on self-study questions is a good point

Answer (score 0):

Denote
\begin{eqnarray*}
z &=&\left( X_{1}-X_{2}\right) ^{2} \\
&=&X_{1}^{2}-2X_{1}X_{2}+X_{2}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left( z\right) =2\sigma ^{2}
$$
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
z^{2} &=&\left( X_{1}-X_{2}\right) ^{4} \\
&=&X_{1}^{4}-4X_{1}^{3}X_{2}+6X_{1}^{2}X_{2}^{2}-4X_{1}X_{2}^{3}+X_{2}^{4}
\end{eqnarray*}
now all you need to remember is that if $X_{1}\sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu
,\sigma ^{2}\right) $ then 
$
\mathbb{E}\left( X_{1}^{3}\right) =\mu ^{3}+3\mu \sigma ^{2}
$
and $\mathbb{E}\left( X_{1}^{4}\right) =\mu ^{4}+6\mu ^{2}\sigma ^{2}+3\sigma ^{4}
$
similarly to $X_{2}$ hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\left( z^{2}\right)  &=&2\left( \mu ^{4}+6\mu ^{2}\sigma
^{2}+3\sigma ^{4}\right) -8\mu \left( \mu ^{3}+3\mu \sigma ^{2}\right)
+6\left( \mu ^{2}+\sigma ^{2}\right) ^{2} \\
&=&12\sigma ^{4}
\end{eqnarray*}%
\begin{eqnarray*}
Var\left( z\right)  &=&\mathbb{E}\left( z^{2}\right) -\left( \mathbb{E}%
\left( z\right) \right) ^{2} \\
&=&12\sigma ^{4}-4\sigma ^{4} \\
&=&8\sigma ^{4}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The proof suggested by MarkL.Stone is more direct. By the way, what software or plug you use to insert those formulas. Thank you again.

Comment: Correct a typo in one of my comment. [(x1-x2)/(2*sigma^2)^(1/2)]^2 follows chi square distribution with freedom 1.

Comment: Yeah you are right there is an easier version of the proof. I supposed here you do not know chi squared. I use scientific work place.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you for your time and patience, I also get it proved.